# How to convert matrix rows to elements of a list in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to extract all elements of a matrix and put them in a vector row-wise.
For example, if my matrix is:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

then, I want to have a vector like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How should I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `c(t(yourmatrix))`:

```
m <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
c(t(m))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```